# Добавление элемента меню из фрагмента. Появляется два одинаковых элемента

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-menu

Создаю fragmentactivity.xml с элементом меню, которое надо добавить. Все как надо подключаю. Код ниже. Но почему-то в меню появляется два одинаковых элемента, в моем случае два Refresh. Как так получается? Как исправить?

sdk version - 21

**ForecastFragment.java**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);

    return rootView;

}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

**menu/menumain.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.example.sunshine.app.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**menu/forecastfragment.xml** (вот этот элемент два раза отображается)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**activity_main.xml** было так

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:name="com.example.srgbotnikov.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

надо так

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.srgbotnikov.sunshine.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело в том, что метод фрагмента **onCreateOptionsMenu** вызывается дважды. Второй раз  - после **onResume**() **activity**. Проверить это можно добавив в тело метода вывод чего-нибудь в консоль.

Если моё предположение верно, то решить сию проблему можно добавкой проверки на наличие пункта меню в методе фрагмента **onCreateOptionsMenu**.

Также проверьте на разных версиях андроида. В зависимости от версии вызов **onCreateOptionsMenu()** активити может происходить в разные моменты жизненного цикла оной. Это нужно для избежания **NPE** при поиске элемента в меню.